# Bibliography subsections in a specific chapter "Bibliographie"

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, tufte-book

When I want to integrate subsections in the bibliography chapter, these are added under the existing Bibliography part, creating a repetition (see the example below ). If I remove the line "\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]" in the MWE below, the subsections appear fine but the title of the chapter "Bibliography" disappears and these are added in the previous chapter, modifying the headings of the bibliographic chapter.
How to solve the problem ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\PrintTufteSettings % Ajout de la ligne
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\geometry{% normal pages % Bloc ajouté jusqu'à ligne 93 (14 lignes)
paperheight  =297mm, paperwidth  = 210mm,  %layout=a4paper
layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
textheight=38\baselineskip,
headheight=\baselineskip,
left=15mm, % right will be the same because of symmetric
bindingoffset= 5mm, % add space for binding
textwidth=90mm,
top=14mm,
marginparsep=6mm,   marginparwidth=40mm,
includehead,
layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,  % 297-240 = 57mm   210-170 = 40mm ->> to center smaller layout in a4
showframe=false,
showcrop=true }

\renewenvironment{fullwidth} % Bloc ajouté jusqu'à ligne 114 (20 lignes)
{\newgeometry{% full width pages
    layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    left=15mm, % right will be the same because of symmetric
    bindingoffset= 5mm, % add space for binding 
    textwidth=136mm, % 90+ 6+ 40
    top=14mm,
    marginparsep=0mm,   marginparwidth=0mm, 
    includehead,
    layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,  % 297-240 = 57mm   210-170 = 40mm ->> to center smaller layout in a4
    showframe=false,
    showcrop=false }

% \TufteRecalculate
\fancyhfoffset[LE]{0pt}
\fancyhfoffset[RO]{0pt}
}   
{\restoregeometry}%
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite}{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}

\addbibresource{sample-handout.bib}



\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}


\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \cleardoublepage        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie} 
    \printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]
    \printbibliography[nottype=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources bibliographiques]
    \printbibliography[type=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources internet]
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of odd bibliography pages]

Here my sample-handout.bib:

```
@BOOK{Buchet,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example1,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example2,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example3,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example4,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}
@BOOK{Example5,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example6,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example7,
    author = {Sueur, Agathe and Dubreuil, Pascal},
    title = {Joachim Burmeister - Poétique musicale, suivi de David Chytraeus - De la Musique},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Rhuthmos},
    year = {2017},
    isbn = {979-10-95155-17-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {288},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Example8,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {Bach en son temps},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    year = {1997},
    isbn = {978-2-213-600007-9},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {658},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Example9,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {J.S. Bach. L'\oe uvre instrumentale},
    publisher = {\'{{E}}ditions Buchet-Chatel},
    year = {2018},
    isbn = {978-2-283-03113-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {475}
}

@INCOLLECTION{Example10,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {{{J}}ean-{{S}}\'{e}bastien {{B}}ach},
    booktitle = {Guide de la musique d'orgue},
    edition = {Premi\`{e}re édition},
    pages = {47-143},
    pagetotal = {840},
    bookauthor = {Cantagrel Gilles},
    isbn = {2-213-02772-2},
    year = {1991},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    place = {Paris}
}

@BOOK{Example11,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example12,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example13,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example14,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}
@BOOK{Example15,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example16,
author = {Buchet, Edmond},
title = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie. Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
year = {1963},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
place = {Saverne},
pagetotal = {267}
}

@BOOK{Example17,
    author = {Sueur, Agathe and Dubreuil, Pascal},
    title = {Joachim Burmeister - Poétique musicale, suivi de David Chytraeus - De la Musique},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Rhuthmos},
    year = {2017},
    isbn = {979-10-95155-17-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {288},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Example18,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {Bach en son temps},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    year = {1997},
    isbn = {978-2-213-600007-9},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {658},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Example19,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {J.S. Bach. L'\oe uvre instrumentale},
    publisher = {\'{{E}}ditions Buchet-Chatel},
    year = {2018},
    isbn = {978-2-283-03113-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {475}
}

@INCOLLECTION{Example20,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {{{J}}ean-{{S}}\'{e}bastien {{B}}ach},
    booktitle = {Guide de la musique d'orgue},
    edition = {Premi\`{e}re édition},
    pages = {47-143},
    pagetotal = {840},
    bookauthor = {Cantagrel Gilles},
    isbn = {2-213-02772-2},
    year = {1991},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    place = {Paris}
}

@BOOK{Burmeister2017,
    author = {Sueur, Agathe and Dubreuil, Pascal},
    title = {Joachim Burmeister - Poétique musicale, suivi de David Chytraeus - De la Musique},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Rhuthmos},
    year = {2017},
    isbn = {979-10-95155-17-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {288},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Canta1997,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {Bach en son temps},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    year = {1997},
    isbn = {978-2-213-600007-9},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {658},
    type = {book},
}

@BOOK{Canta2018,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {J.S. Bach. L'\oe uvre instrumentale},
    publisher = {\'{{E}}ditions Buchet-Chatel},
    year = {2018},
    isbn = {978-2-283-03113-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {475}
}

@INCOLLECTION{Canta1991,
    author = {Cantagrel, Gilles},
    title = {{{J}}ean-{{S}}\'{e}bastien {{B}}ach},
    booktitle = {Guide de la musique d'orgue},
    edition = {Premi\`{e}re édition},
    pages = {47-143},
    pagetotal = {840},
    bookauthor = {Cantagrel Gilles},
    isbn = {2-213-02772-2},
    year = {1991},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Fayard},
    place = {Paris}
}

@BOOK{Dufourq1948,
    author = {Dufourq, Norbert},
    title = {Jean-Sébastien Bach - Le maître de l'orgue},
    publisher = {\'{E}ditions Picard},
    edition = {Troisi\`{e}me édition},
    year = {1984},
    isbn = {2-7084-0099-1},
    place = {Paris},
    pagetotal = {400},
    type = {book},
}

@MISC{Bachdigital,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Portail {{B}}ach pour la recherche et la pratique musicale},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/content/index.xed}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital2,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Leonhard {{S}}cholz (1720 - 1798). Organiste, papetier et marchand sp\'{e}cialis\'{e} \`{a} {{N}}uremberg},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/staticpages/bio/scholz_l.html}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital3,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital4,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
    }

@MISC{Bachdigital5,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Leonhard {{S}}cholz (1720 - 1798). Organiste, papetier et marchand sp\'{e}cialis\'{e} \`{a} {{N}}uremberg},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/staticpages/bio/scholz_l.html}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital6,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital7,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
    }

@MISC{Bachdigital8,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Portail {{B}}ach pour la recherche et la pratique musicale},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/content/index.xed}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital9,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Leonhard {{S}}cholz (1720 - 1798). Organiste, papetier et marchand sp\'{e}cialis\'{e} \`{a} {{N}}uremberg},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/staticpages/bio/scholz_l.html}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital10,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital11,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
    }

@MISC{Bachdigital12,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Leonhard {{S}}cholz (1720 - 1798). Organiste, papetier et marchand sp\'{e}cialis\'{e} \`{a} {{N}}uremberg},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/staticpages/bio/scholz_l.html}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital13,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
}

@MISC{Bachdigital14,
    author = {Bach~Digital},
    title = {Mempell {{J.N.}}, {{P}}artition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
    year = {2008-2020},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352}}
    }
```

Comment: By "a repetition", do you mean that there is a set A of entries after the main heading, a set B after the first sub-heading and a set C after the second, and that A=B+C ? Whereas you'd like to have only the disjoint sets B and C *and the heading* "Bibliographie"? If so, you only need `\chapter*{Bibliographie}`, and not `\printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]`. Because this, unsurprisingly, *prints the whole bibliography*. Which of course is what the sum of `nottype=misc` and `type=misc` amounts to: the whole bibliography. Hence the repetition.

Comment: @marquinho There is also `\printbibheading` which only typesets the heading and might be more elegant in some cases. I would have suggested `\printbibheading[heasing=bibintoc, title={Bibliographie}]` here, so we can also get rid of the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}`, but the `bibintoc` heading is explicitly redefined not to add the heading to the ToC, so I need to wait for a working MWE before I want to say anything more.

Comment: I updated my question to answer to @moewe

Comment: Your code still errors because it has `\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}` before `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`. *Please* test your code before you submit it and make sure that it actually shows the issue you are asking about. Code that produces unrelated errors always makes me suspect that those who posted it did not actually run it and did not actually verify that it reproduces the issue they are asking about.

Comment: Note that even with the entries you give the bibliography consist only of a single page and therefore does not have column heads in the header. It may therefore not be appropriate to assess whether `\markboth` and friends work as expected.

Comment: @Phil8544 I second moewe's request for a compilable (the "W" in "MWE") example. Also, could you comment on whether I got your request right? You want (1) a chapter-level *heading* "Bibliographie", but 0 entries, then (2) two *bibliographies*, each with ~10 entries (and a sub-heading)? Because then moewe's tip with `\printbibheading` would solve it.

Comment: @marquinho Your answer solves my problem for the repetition (But suddenly the chapter uses the heading of the previous chapter and not "Bibliographie"). And yes, I want a chapter-level heading "Bibliographie" and not "BIBLIOGRAPHIE". I will add some examples in sample-handout.bib and I will try the \printbibheading. I'm looking for the error in the code presented in the MWE (work in progress...)

Comment: I now get `! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 3.`. Line 3 is `\ifx\ifxetex\ifluatex\else` and looks pretty odd.

Comment: If I delete that line I get `! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.` somewhere in between all those `\autocite`s. I doubt they are needed, you can probably just say `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: I believe I really need to know how one can easily insert a code in the questions, because the method I use is very tedious from overleaf...

Comment: I now managed to run your example, but unlike in your image there is no "BIBLIOGRAPHY" in the header/column title. Do you want that column title? Can you see it in your actual document?

Comment: The header "Bibliography" also disappeared on my document following the modification that I applied following Marquino's first remark (you only need \chapter*{Bibliography}, and not \printbibliography[title={Bibliography}])...

Comment: I'm confused. For me there is *no* column head (all caps "BIBLIOGRAPHIE" as shown in the screenshot) in the code you show. I did not change `\printbibliography` to `\chapter*`. But the question remains: Do you actually want the column head?

Comment: Alright, the missing headers were due to a missing `\mainmatter`, so just an issue with the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\printbibheading` to print just the (overall) bibliography heading, then you can use `\printbibliography` for the sub-bibliographies.

The layout you want would be given by

```
\begin{fullwidth}
  \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliographie}]
  \printbibliography[nottype=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources bibliographiques]
  \printbibliography[type=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources internet]
\end{fullwidth}
```

but if you add that to your code, things won't work correctly, because

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}
```

redefines `bibintoc` in a way that causes it to no longer work as advertised.

Remove the block

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}
```

from your code.

While you are at it, also remove

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}
```

With the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\PrintTufteSettings

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\geometry{%
paperheight  =297mm, paperwidth  = 210mm,  %layout=a4paper
layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
textheight=38\baselineskip,
headheight=\baselineskip,
left=15mm,
bindingoffset= 5mm, % add space for binding
textwidth=90mm,
top=14mm,
marginparsep=6mm,   marginparwidth=40mm,
includehead,
layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,
showframe=false,
showcrop=true }

\renewenvironment{fullwidth}
{\newgeometry{% full width pages
    layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    left=15mm,
    bindingoffset= 5mm,
    textwidth=136mm, 
    top=14mm,
    marginparsep=0mm,   marginparwidth=0mm,
    includehead,
    layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,
    showframe=false,
    showcrop=false }


\fancyhfoffset[LE]{0pt}
\fancyhfoffset[RO]{0pt}
}
{\restoregeometry}%

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{Bachdigital,
  author = {{Bach Digital}},
  title  = {Portail {Bach} pour la recherche et la pratique musicale},
  date   = {2008/2020},
  url    = {https://www.bach-digital.de/content/index.xed},
}
@MISC{Bachdigital2,
  author = {{Bach Digital}},
  title  = {Leonhard {Scholz} (1720 - 1798).
            Organiste, papetier et marchand sp\'{e}cialis\'{e} \`{a} {Nuremberg}},
  date   = {2008/2020},
  url    = {https://www.bach-digital.de/staticpages/bio/scholz_l.html},
}
@MISC{Bachdigital3,
  author = {{Bach Digital}},
  title  = {Mempell {J.N.},
            Partition, compilation manuscrite en 1730-1740 au sein d'une liasse},
  date   = {2008/2020},
  url    = {https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalSource_source_00003352},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1-25]

\nocite{*}

\begin{fullwidth}
  \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliographie}]
  \printbibliography[nottype=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources bibliographiques]
  \printbibliography[type=misc,heading=subbibintoc,title=Sources internet]
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image: "Bibliographie" as overall heading, then "Sources bibliographiques" as subheading, followed by the bib entries]

[image: running head: "BIBLIOGRAPHIE" on left pages.]

[image: "Sources internet" subbibliography]

If you don't want the running headers in all caps, add

```
\providecommand*{\MakeMarkcase}[1]{#1}
```

after you load `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which answers my question. I'm surprised to have the header "BIBLIOGRAPHY" in capital letters and not in normal text... Besides, I'm not sure I understood correctly: you expect me to correct the code of my question with your update to be clearer? If so no problem, I will be willing to do so.

Comment: @Phil8544 See the edit for a way to get rid of the all caps. (You will still get a header in small caps, though.)